# Java Exception Handling and loop continuation

Tags: java, while-loop, exception

So this is for a HW problem.  It is a guessing game for numbers between 1 and 10. I had to create two exception classes:
1. to handle guesses
2. if the user exceeds 5 guesses

There is also a third requirement for if the user enters an incorrect format (however that did not require me to make an additional exception class.

My problem is that I want to the user to have 5 attempts no matter what they enter, whether it's five or 15.  I was able to do this for any guesses outside of the range, but when I enter an invalid format, such as "five" the loop becomes infinite.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you in advance:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5; // Stores maximum number of attempts
        int answer; // Stores answer
        int attempts = 1; // Stores nubmer of attempts
        int guess; // Stores user's guess
        boolean checkAnswer = true; // Loop control variable

        // Create Scanner object for keyboard input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Generate random nubmer between 1 and 10
        answer = generateNumber();

        /**
         * Allow user to guess (up to five times) what the random number is. Includes
         * exception handling for guesses that are outside of the range of 1 and 10,
         * have exceeded 5 guesses, and are invalid formats and/or data types.
         **/
        while (checkAnswer) {
            try {
                // Prompt user for input
                System.out.println("Please guess a number between 1 and 10");
                System.out.println("HINT: " + answer);
                guess = keyboard.nextInt();

                // Throw exception if user exceeds 5 guesses
                if (attempts > MAX_ATTEMPTS)
                    throw new TooManyGuessesException(attempts);
                // Throw exception if user guesses outside of range
                else if ((guess > 10) || (guess < 1))
                    throw new BadGuessException(guess);

                // Prompt user that guess is correct and exit loop
                else if (guess == answer) {
                    if (attempts == 1)
                        System.out.println("YOU WIN!! Wow!! You made " 
                            + attempts 
                            + " attempt and guessed it on the "
                            + "first try!");
                    else
                        System.out.println("YOU WIN!! You made " + attempts + " attempts");
                    checkAnswer = false;
                } else {
                    attempts++; // increment attempts if no correct guess
                }

            }
            // Handles guesses that are outside of range
            catch (BadGuessException e) {
                attempts++;
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                continue;
            }
            // Handles exception if user exceeds maximum attempts
            catch (TooManyGuessesException e) {
                checkAnswer = false;
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            // Handles exception if user enters incorrect format
            catch (Exception e) {
                attempts++;
                System.out.println("Sorry, you entered an invalid number " + "format.");
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * <b>generateNumber method</b>
     * <p>
     * Generates and returns 1 random number between 1 and 10 inclusive
     * </p>
     * 
     * @return A random number between 1 and 10 inclusive.
     */
    public static int generateNumber() {
        int randomNumber; // Store lotto number 1
        final int RANGE = 10; // Sets range of random number

        // Create random object
        Random rand = new Random();

        // Generate a random value
        randomNumber = rand.nextInt(RANGE) + 1;

        return randomNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear about your requirement. Do you want the user to try 5 times even he entered invalid format, like "five" ?

Comment: Actually your program finishes after stepping into `catch(Exception e)` because you break the loop.

Comment: Unrelated: please use { braces } always, even for single if/else blocks. It is so easy to get these things wrong, so always always use full blocks.

Comment: No matter what the motivation behind the task is (homework, fiddeling or productive code) using Exceptions for control flow is always bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter 'five',  method nextInt() throws InputMismatchException, after thet you get inside catch block and breaks the loop.

```
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        attempts++;
        System.out.println("Sorry, you entered an invalid number "
                + "format.");
        break;
    }
```

[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html)

> 14.12.1. Abrupt Completion of while Statement
> Abrupt completion of the contained Statement is handled in the following manner:
>
> If execution of the Statement completes abruptly because of a break with no label, no >further action is taken and the while statement completes normally.
>
> If execution of the Statement completes abruptly because of a continue with no label, >then the entire while statement is executed again.
>
> If execution of the Statement completes abruptly because of a continue with label L, >then there is a choice:
>
> If the while statement has label L, then the entire while statement is executed again.
>
> If the while statement does not have label L, the while statement completes abruptly >because of a continue with label L.
>
> If execution of the Statement completes abruptly for any other reason, the while >statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
>
> The case of abrupt completion because of a break with a label is handled by the general >rule for labeled statements (§14.7).

Comment: sorry, I just realized I had "break"  I was getting errors when using "continue" and switched to "break" but that's not really how  I wanted to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `nextInt()` but the next data is not an int, you get an exception.

NOTE: This doesn't then consume the word which caused a problem, it just throws an exception.

So when you try again, you get the same result.  Most likely you want to discard the rest of the line of text.  I would add a call to `nextLine()` to read the remainder of the line before trying again.

Comment: @NamNgo you can upvote and tick the answer to accept it if you like.